# HTML default font sizes

Tags: html, fonts

Do the HTML font tags (like p and h3) have default font sizes universally in all browsers? For example, I'd imagine p is around 16px or so. Is there a standardized list someone could link me off to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers can implement any size they want to and usually do. That's why you should always implement a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) of your own. This way you are sure all browsers use the same default styles for all HTML elements. There are [a lot to choose from](https://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css%20reset) but if you look around you can see they all follow the same basic principles.

Comment: Thanks for the information, very helpful. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

user-agents defaults typically differ, from little subtleties, to horrible travesties (trident :) ). these sites cover the vast amount of the most popular ua's today:

http://meiert.com/en/blog/20070922/user-agent-style-sheets/
http://www.iecss.com/

older ua defaults: http://css-class.com/test/css/defaults/UA-style-sheet-defaults.htm